# Makefile target-based dependencies with a wildcard (compact)

Tags: makefile

I would like to apply the following code in a more compact way:

```
hello1:
    @echo "Hello1"

hello2:
    @echo "Hello2"

hello3:
    @echo "Hello3"

hello_all:  hello1 hello2 hello3
```

Is there a way of coding `hello_all` dependencies with a wildcard, e.g. hello* or something?

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post a real-world example, the answer's probably going to be "no" but it's impossible to say for sure unless you explain what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, my goal it to create a single target for running a regression that contains lots of tests with a similar name.  Currently, each tests has its own make target, and I want to call all of these targets (with a similar name) from the new regression target

Comment: @ShaharGino Could you give us an example of a test recipe? I'd like to know if they are very different from each other or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your targets are very similar, go with @TimF's solution as it avoids repetition. If they are different and can't be generalized, you can do this with a small helper:

```
hello-add = $(eval HELLO_TARGETS += $1)$1

$(call hello-add,hello1):
    @echo "Hello1"

$(call hello-add,hello2):
    @echo "Hello2"

$(call hello-add,hello3):
    @echo "Hello3"

hello_all: $(HELLO_TARGETS)
```

`hello-add` accepts an argument, adds it to the `HELLO_TARGETS` variable, and expands to exactly that argument (because `eval` expands to empty). It behaves like:

```
HELLO_TARGETS += hello1
hello1:
    ...
```

But avoids having to write the target name twice.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, it indeed seems clean, but it doesn't work, as I'm getting the following error when trying to use make hello_all:    Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: @ShaharGino Did you copypaste without replacing the 4-space indentation with tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a native way to do it. Find below a solution specific to your usecase. I think however that it cannot easily be used in a generic way.

```
# The number list that will be used to generate the targets
NUMBERS = 1 2 3 4 

# Function that will expand to a custom helloX target, with X the number given as parameter
# Note the strip that removes the spaces in the parameter
define createHelloTargets
HELLO_TARGETS += hello$(strip $(1))
hello$(strip $(1)):
    @echo Hello$(strip $(1))
endef

# Generate one Hello target for each number in NUMBERS
$(foreach nb, $(NUMBERS), $(eval $(call createHelloTargets, $(nb))))

all: $(HELLO_TARGETS)
```

This will output :

> Hello1
>
> Hello2
>
> Hello3
>
> Hello4

The advantage is that you don't have to write each target, just fill the NUMBERS var and it does the trick.

Basically, this Makefile will create for each number X in NUMBERS a target that looks like this :

```
helloX:
    @echo HelloX
```

It will also add `helloX` to `HELLO_TARGETS` which is a list of all the existing helloX targets. This list is expanded in the `all` target prerequisites.